# MathJax not working well

Tags: android, mathjax

I'm trying to make MathJax to work in my Android App.

```
MyWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http//","<html><script type=\"text/x-mathjax-config\"> MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}}); </script> <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML\"> </script><body><b>a)</b> " + myText.replaceAll("%", "&#37;")+"</body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Its not working, myText stays as it is, and no mathematic formula appears. Any idea what could it be? anything wrong in the way im using it?

Obs.: The following message is appearing in the console, maybe it has something to do with MathJax not working:

[INFO:CONSOLE(29)] "Unchaught SecurityError: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.", source: https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML (29)

Comment: I have the same problem. What can  I do ?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but why are you not shipping a slim copy of MathJax? See http://www.mathjax.org/community/mathjax-in-use/mathjax-in-use-instructions-and-how-tos/ for a sample app.

Comment: Tried using a copy of MathJax, but doesnt work as well. That same message appears even using this copy (not calling the cloud MathJax). Seems to be some peculiarity of my App because I did another App that worked perfectly using MathJax as described in the tutorial of the MathJax Website.

Comment: is your problem solved. Because I am still facing the same issue

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).